# OrderBy().ThenBy() wrong output

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, point

I have a list of Points with 50 elements, I wanted to sort them so I used orderby thenby to, but my output seems to be wrong. The first elements are sorted in accordingly, but the next ones are wrong, here is a screen shot.

[image]

The 1st five data where sorted correctly, that should be what the other data would be. but the next ones are not. I don't know what is the problem.

So the next five output must be:

```
{X=249, Y=198}

{X=249, Y=308}

{X=249, Y=413}

{X=249, Y=519}

{X=249, Y=629}
```

My list is a PointF list:

```
List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
```

Here is my code:

```
points = points.OrderBy(c => c.X).ThenBy(c => c.Y).ToList();
```

Comment: My suspicion is that your X values are not exact. For example, you might have X=249 and X=249.00000001 on different points. Try modifying the code to `OrderBy(c=>Math.Floor(c.X)).ThenBy(c=>c.Y)`

Comment: @Zruty: Very plausible; you should post that as an answer!

Comment: @Zruty you're answer provided me the correct output, I don't understand why. Thanks zruty! +1

Comment: I got wrong output also, as I've said with your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please verify that your points' X values are indeed equal. I assume both `249` and `249.000001` may get rendered as "249" in a listbox, but will not be equal for the ordering purposes.

I suggest changing your code to

```
points = points.OrderBy(c => Math.Round(c.X)).ThenBy(c => c.Y).ToList();
```

and seeing if the problem is gone.

**UPDATE:** if your coordinates are expected to be non-integers, switch to comparing with specified precision:

```
var precision = 0.001; // choose the value that suits you. If the tow values are different by less than this amount, the values are considered equal.
points = points.OrderBy(c => Math.Round(c.X / precision)).ThenBy(c => c.Y).ToList();
```

Also, instead of using `Round(c.X)` you could use `(int)c.X`, since your comments indicate that this is how you output your values to the listbox.

Comment: I tried that method, but I gives wrong result. because, what if for example there is x = 249 , y=360 and x = 249.6 , y = 180. The second x-coordinate will be rounded to 250. so when sorted it would be

 {X=250, Y=160} then {X=249, Y=360}

Comment: hey @Zruty, your solution gave me the correct answer. thank you somuch. But I don't clearly understand how it worked, I know precision works like a threshold or something?

Comment: This is because float values are not precisely represented. Because of that, for example, `0.1*0.1` is not equal to `0.01`. That's why comparing float values for equality doesn't always work, and typically instead of `a==b` a different form is used: `Math.Abs(a-b) < very_small_number`.
For additional info, start with a wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems